# MongoDB: Count by unique value after aggregate by group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to get count unique values by group.
Here is the example data:

```
[
   {
     iphone: iphone6,
     name: Tom
   },
   {
     iphone:iphone7,
     name: Tom
   },
   {
     iphone:iphone6,
     name: Joe
   },
   {
     iphone:iphoneX,
     name: Joe
   }
]
```

I want to group by showing like:

```
[
   {
     _id:iphone6,
     people:[Tom,Joe]
   },
   {
     _id:iphone7,
     people:[Tom]
   },
   {
     _id:iphoneX,
     people:[Joe]
   }
]
```

I have a problem with using `$group`. How can I do this?

Comment: @YongShun Sorry didn't notice it. Forget to add "iphone"

Comment: try mongodb documentation its very good with many examples

Comment: @Takis_ Sure. I should play more on that kind of mongo query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$group`: Group by `iphone` and `$push` `name` to `people` array field.
2. `$sort` (Optional): Sort by `_id` ascending.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$iphone",
      people: {
        $push: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8CSdQOgbMir)

Comment: Thanks. New to MongoDb area. Didn't know we can use command like "$push" under other aggregate command.